# Raspberry Pi 4 stuck on Rainbow Screen

Tags: boot-issues, noobs, pi-4

My Raspberry Pi turns on, it shows the Rainbow Screen, then freezes. I have not installed Raspbian; I downloaded NOOBS and put it on my micro SDHC card. I put the micro SDHC card into the slot and turn on power. It then turns on and shows the Rainbow Screen and freezes. I do not see any text nor Raspberries.

Data:

Raspberry Pi 4
Has official Raspberry Pi keyboard hub plugged in
Also has official Raspberry Pi mouse plugged into the keyboard/hub
Uses official Raspberry Pi power supply
micro SDHC card is a 32GB card from Micro Center
I also used a micro SD adapter also from Micro Center
I downloaded the newest NOOBS at time of post: Version 3.2.1 Released 2019-09-20
 I used the official SD card formatter (I used the link in the [Setting Up Your Raspberry Pi](https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/raspberry-pi-setting-up) tutorial)
I tried using both Quick format and Full Overwrite on the card

I did use a 8GB card and it worked on my Pi, but I had to use a SD card with a bigger capacity.

I am a beginner at Raspberry Pi.