# Does NOOBS showing/freezing on the Rainbow screen mean that the microSD card reader is working?

Tags: boot-issues, pi-4, noobs

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 with NOOBS. When I try to boot NOOBS it shows the rainbow screen and then freezes. I have limited the possible reasons why it won't boot to either my 32GB card is not formatted correctly or that my Raspberry Pi is broken. So, I am asking "Does NOOBS showing/freezing on the Rainbow screen mean that the microSD card reader is working?".

If you think you can fix my Rainbow screen problem please see [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/106629/raspberry-pi-4-stuck-on-rainbow-screen).

Comment: Why do you use NOOBs? It's known to create a lot of trouble. Use plain raspbian instead.

Comment: Don't use noobs, flash 'Raspbian with Desktop' (don't unzip) direct to sd card with Etcher. https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/ https://www.balena.io/etcher/

Comment: why do you feel that a failure means that hardware is working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Pi4 Boot Problems Sticky](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151&sid=ec118b286843110a1175ec84a250a7dc#p1485558) contains detailed troubleshooting steps.

Using [NOOBS](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/92069/8697) just makes fault finding harder.

The rainbow screen is due to missing (or obsolete) firmware.

I suggest you use Etcher to install Raspbian to a SD Card (like the vast bulk of us).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Pi 4, make sure you connect to exact HDMI0 port as shown in the picture. Otherwise, you will see a static rainbow image on the monitor.[image]